# python: efficient way to check only a couple of rows in a csvreader iterator?

Tags: python, csv

I have a (very large) CSV file that looks something like this:

```
header1,header2,header3
name0,rank0,serial0
name1,rank1,serial1
name2,rank2,serial2
```

I've written some code that processes the file, and writes it out (using csvwriter) modified as such, with some information I compute appended to the end of each row:

```
header1,header2,header3,new_hdr4,new_hdr5
name0,rank0,serial0,salary0,base0
name1,rank1,serial1,salary1,base1
name2,rank2,serial2,salary2,base2
```

What I'm trying to do is structure the script so that it auto-detects whether or not the CSV file it's reading has ***already been processed***.  If it has been processed, I can skip a lot of expensive calculations later.  I'm trying to understand whether there is a reasonable way of doing this within the reader loop.  I *could* just open the file once, read in enough to do the detection, and then close and reopen it with a flag set, but this seems hackish.

Is there a way to do this within the same reader?  The logic is something like:

```
read first N lines   ###(N is small)
   if (some condition)
      already_processed = TRUE
      read_all_csv_without_processing
   else
      read_all_csv_WITH_processing
```

I can't just use the iterator that reader gives me, because by the time I've gotten enough lines to do my conditional check, I don't have any good way to go back to the beginning of the CSV.  Is closing and reopening it really the most elegant way to do this?

Comment: Your own solution is the best: open the file, read a few lines, close the file and reopen the file. Then start a loop with a flag set if processed or not. It is not hackish at all to do that. Opening and closing files is pretty fast, and as a benefit, the file data will probably still be in the OS file cache when you reread a second time.

Comment: Why not just keep a record of what you have processed?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: that's basically what I'm doing - I want the code to be able to tell whether it's reading a "processed" CSV or a "raw" CSV by the existence of the new fields.  *If* I'm opening a file that has already been run against, I still need to update a number of internal data structures, but there's a large part of the processing that can be skipped.  I initially tried pickling the "fully processed" data structure, but it took just as long to open the pickle file as it did to recreate it from the raw data.  (Which I thought was odd, but I tested that multiple times...)

Comment: You don't pickle the file, you pickle the *set of filenames* that you have already processed.

Comment: Ah - yes: now I see what you mean.  This might work in general, but in my case I cannot guarantee that the filenames are consistent/static over time - in some cases I get files with the same name, and the contents of "foo.csv" must be inspected to determine whether foo.csv is a processed or a raw file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the usual python method to read the file (`with open("file.csv","r") as f:` or equivalent), you can "reset" the file reading by calling `f.seek(0)`.

Here is a piece of code that should (I guess) look a bit more like the way you're reading your file. It demonstate that reseting `csvfile` with `csvfile.seek(0)` will also reset `csvreader`:

```
with open('so.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',') 
    for row in csvreader:
        print('Checking if processed')
        print(', '.join(row))
        #if condition:
        if True:
            print('File already processed')
            already_processed = True
            print('Reseting the file')
            csvfile.seek(0)
            for row in csvreader:
                print(', '.join(row))
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if you do not want to just test the first few lines of the file, you could create a single iterator from a  list and then the continuation of the csv reader.

Given:

```
header1,header2,header3
name0,rank0,serial0
name1,rank1,serial1
name2,rank2,serial2
```

You can do:

```
import csv
from itertools import chain

with open(fn) as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    header=next(reader)
    N=2
    p_list=[]
    for i in range(N):   # N is however many you need to set processed flag
        p_list.append(next(reader))
    print("p_list:", p_list)
    # now use p_list to determine if processed however processed=check(p_list)

    for row in chain(iter(p_list), reader):  # chain creates a single csv reader...
        # handler processed or not here from the stream of rows...
        # if not processed:
        #     process
        # else:
        #     handle already processed...
        # print row just to show csv data is complete:
        print(row)
```

Prints:

```
p_list: [['name0', 'rank0', 'serial0'], ['name1', 'rank1', 'serial1']]
['name0', 'rank0', 'serial0']
['name1', 'rank1', 'serial1']
['name2', 'rank2', 'serial2']
```

Comment: `itertools.islice` can replace a lot of the logic

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to achieve is to use the first lines to decide between the type of processing, then re-use those lines for your read_all_csv_WITH_processing or read_all_csv_without_processing, while still not loading the full csv file in-memory. To achieve that you can load the first lines in a list and concatenate that with the rest of the file with itertools.chain, like this:

```
import itertools

top_lines = []
reader_iterator = csv.reader(fil)
do_heavy_processing = True
while True:
    # Can't use "for line in reader_iterator" directly, otherwise we're
    # going to close the iterator when going out of the loop after the first
    # N iterations
    line = reader_iterator.__next__()
    top_lines.append(line)
    if some_condition(line):
        do_heavy_processing = False
        break
    elif not_worth_going_further(line)
        break
full_file = itertools.chain(top_lines, reader_iterator)

if do_heavy_processing:
    read_all_csv_WITH_processing(full_file)
else:
    read_all_csv_without_processing(full_file)
```

Answer (score -1):

I will outline what I consider a much better approach. I presume this is happening over various runs. What you need to do is persist the files seen between runs and only process what has not been seen:

```
import pickle
import glob


def process(fle):
    # read_all_csv_with_processing

def already_process(fle):
    # read_all_csv_without_processing
try:
    # if it exists, we ran the code previously.
  with open("seen.pkl", "rb") as f:
     seen = pickle.load(f)
except IOError as  e:
    # Else first run, so just create the set.
    print(e)
    seen = set()

for file in glob.iglob("path_where_files_are/*.csv"):
    # if not seen before, just process
    if file not in seen:
        process(file)
    else:
        # already processed so just do whatever
        already_process(file)
    seen.add(file)

# persist the set.
with open("seen.pkl", "w") as f:
    pickle.dumps(seen, f)
```

Even if for some strange reason you somehow process the same files in the same run, all you need to do then is implement the seen set logic.

Another alternative would be to use a unique marker in the file that you add at the start if processed.

```
# something here
header1,header2,header3,new_hdr4,new_hdr5
name0,rank0,serial0,salary0,base0
name1,rank1,serial1,salary1,base1
name2,rank2,serial2,salary2,base2
```

Then all you would need to process is the very first line. Also if you want to get the first n lines from a file even if you wanted to [start from a certain row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064374/iterate-from-a-certain-row-of-a-csv-file-in-python/38064407#38064407), use [itertools.islce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

To be robust you might want to wrap your code in a try/finally in case it errors so you don't end up going over the same files already processed on the next run:

```
try:
    for file in glob.iglob("path_where_files_are/*.csv"):
        # if not seen before, just process
        if file not in seen:
            process(file)
        else:
            # already processed so just do whatever
            already_process(file)
        seen.add(file)
finally: 
    # persist the set.
    with open("seen.pkl", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(seen, f)
```